# Yum Installs Could not Resolve Host

Tags: centos, yum

When i try to install packages via `yum` on CentOS, I get this error message.

```
http://mirrors.service.networklayer.com/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/atk-devel-1.30.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrors.service.networklayer.com'"
```

I have tried edit the yum config file to use Http istead of Https instead but still no luck.

Comment: It seems that `mirrors.service.networklayer.com` is not valid. You have to change this in your yum configuration.

Comment: What would this have to be changed to?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the mirror you have in the repo file is not reachable from your network. Make sure you are connected to the network and the mirrors are reachable, may be try pinging the mirror's site. 
Also use a better (nearer/faster) and available mirror from the following centos mirrors: 
https://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/